# How to share MATLAB variable data to a C++ program running on a different computer?

Tags: c++, matlab, arduino, ipc, robotics

I have an optical sensor that is controlled by a robot. Currently I have two independent threads, each in a different (win 7) PC:

1. Imaging probe: camera takes image, MATLAB process the img data, crunches data.
2. Robotic actuator: probe is moved by this actuator, the control code runs on C++

I would like to share some of the processed data from (1) to (2).

**Question:**
How do I share in REAL-TIME MATLAB variable data to a C++ program running on a different computer?

Ideas/constraints I have so far:

- Serial RS232 port of (1) is in use by some imaging hardware.
- Ethernet could be used, how?
- Two arduinos: [serial](http://robotic-controls.com/learn/arduino/arduino-arduino-serial-communication) or I2C, USB connection to each PC?

Any suggestion is more than welcome!

Comment: If you can't find help here, maybe someone on the [Arduino Stack Exchange forum](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/) can help you.

Comment: For Ethernet communication, you can use [TCP](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2011/05/27/transferring-data-between-two-computers-using-matlab/) or [UDP](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/97014-how-do-i-send-data-between-two-computers-using-the-udp-function-from-the-instrument-control-toolbox).

Comment: Thanks @Rotem indeed, UDP was the solution